# Number of app installs is 5x of the 'first opens' with google ads? How to measure number of real app installs?

Tags: android, google-play, ads, firebase-analytics

I ran a google ads campaign for app installs. At the end of it, Google ads dashboard shows 55 'installs' and my logs shows number of 'first opens' as 12. App size is 10MB and should take 10-20 seconds on a 4G network.

Why there is a huge discrepancy?
I am assuming most people should open the app atleast once after installing it. 
Is there a way to check number of install by myself? Possibly using firebase-analytics library?

I am tracking 'first opens' using firebase analytics. I tried to check number of receives by sending pushes but pushes are being sent to only  first opens. So even sending pushes didn't work.

Comment: Bit of a guess: does the 55 number measure the number of times the install process _was started_ or the number of times it _completed_? Maybe some people start installation (perhaps without fully realizing it) and then cancel installation?

Comment: Can't say, didn't find any documentation on the same.
As per google ads dashboard, number of downloads(and also number of app installs) is mentioned to be 55. 
App size was 10mb, so i think it wouldn't explain the 4x factor.

Comment: google ads campaign is like a black box The result can be difficult to comprehend . It's run by their AI and machine learning. But firebase result I think are accurate and you should consider them as actual app install.